# git pull not downloading files from server

Tags: git

I was able to do the git pull from our master branch earlier. Suddenly one day, when I do git pull from master or any other branch it is not working. There is no error in the terminal. Just cursor stands there where it is.

I am able to create new branch locally and able to git add and git commit but not able to git push.

I'm not sure why it is. When I tried to delete the branches locally, I got message **The branch 'featureA' is not fully merged**

Then I deleted that branch using the command `git branch -D featureA`. 
Like this, I have deleted all my local branches that are not pushed to the server.

Even after, git pull is not working.

Please share if you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all check to see that you still have permissions and the branch is not locked for pushes.

   - Try to push new branch - in order to verify that you can push to the repository

     ```
     # Create empty branch just for testing
     git checkout --orphan test1

     # Add empty commit 
     git commit --allow-empty -m"test"

     # Now try to push the branch to verify that you have permissions on the repo
     git push origin test1
     ```
2. Verify that you are able to fetch from the repository

   ```
   # Fetch all remotes if you have more than 1
   git fetch --all --prune
   ```
3. Check that you did not updated the remote

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```

Please update if its working or not since there can be many other reasons and ways to check it. You need to supply some direction and more details

Comment: git push origin test1 and git fetch --all --prune are not doing anything. After git fetch --all --prune, I am able to get origin (fetch) and origin (push). Both are correct cloning url.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is not an issue with your Internet connectivity, and you have a write permission on the repo.

A second solution would be to use -v flag with your git pull.

And the last one I would propose you to git clone the remote repo in another directory and see if it works.

Comment: Git clone is also not working for me. I suspect it may related with SSH connectivity issue with git